# Geoserver: Adding a WFS Service access rule prevents all users from performing WFS requests

Tags: geoserver

I need to restrict access to WFS services on admins only, so in the Services Access Rules list I add the following rule

```
wfs.*=ADMIN
```

Then I logged in as an ADMIN, and try to excute one of the WFS requests from the demos, but the request return asking me for login credentials.
I tried login with the root user, the same problem happens !!

Here are my security configurations:

config.xml:

```
<security>
  <roleServiceName>default</roleServiceName>
  <authProviderNames>
    <string>default</string>
  </authProviderNames>
  <configPasswordEncrypterName>pbePasswordEncoder</configPasswordEncrypterName>
  <encryptingUrlParams>false</encryptingUrlParams>
  <filterChain>
    <filters name="web" class="org.geoserver.security.HtmlLoginFilterChain" interceptorName="interceptor" exceptionTranslationName="exception" path="/web/**,/gwc/rest/web/**,/,/wcs*,/wfs*" disabled="false" allowSessionCreation="true" ssl="false" matchHTTPMethod="false">
      <filter>rememberme</filter>
      <filter>form</filter>
      <filter>anonymous</filter>
    </filters>
    <filters name="webLogin" class="org.geoserver.security.ConstantFilterChain" path="/j_spring_security_check,/j_spring_security_check/" disabled="false" allowSessionCreation="true" ssl="false" matchHTTPMethod="false">
      <filter>form</filter>
    </filters>
    <filters name="webLogout" class="org.geoserver.security.LogoutFilterChain" path="/j_spring_security_logout,/j_spring_security_logout/" disabled="false" allowSessionCreation="false" ssl="false" matchHTTPMethod="false">
      <filter>formLogout</filter>
    </filters>
    <filters name="rest" class="org.geoserver.security.ServiceLoginFilterChain" interceptorName="restInterceptor" exceptionTranslationName="exception" path="/rest/**" disabled="false" allowSessionCreation="false" ssl="false" matchHTTPMethod="false">
      <filter>basic</filter>
    </filters>
    <filters name="gwc" class="org.geoserver.security.ServiceLoginFilterChain" interceptorName="restInterceptor" exceptionTranslationName="exception" path="/gwc/rest/**" disabled="false" allowSessionCreation="false" ssl="false" matchHTTPMethod="false">
      <filter>basic</filter>
    </filters>
    <filters name="default" class="org.geoserver.security.ServiceLoginFilterChain" interceptorName="interceptor" exceptionTranslationName="exception" path="/**" disabled="false" allowSessionCreation="false" ssl="false" matchHTTPMethod="false">
      <filter>basic</filter>
    </filters>
  </filterChain>
  <rememberMeService>
    <className>org.geoserver.security.rememberme.GeoServerTokenBasedRememberMeServices</className>
    <key>geoserver</key>
  </rememberMeService>
  <bruteForcePrevention>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
    <minDelaySeconds>1</minDelaySeconds>
    <maxDelaySeconds>5</maxDelaySeconds>
    <maxBlockedThreads>100</maxBlockedThreads>
    <whitelistedMasks>
      <string>127.0.0.1</string>
    </whitelistedMasks>
  </bruteForcePrevention>
</security>
```

layers.properties:

```
*.*.a=ADMIN
mode=HIDE
```

services.properties:

```
*.*=*
wfs.*=ADMIN
```

Comment: currently, I think the demos page always asks for a login - try with CURL or other program to test access constraints

Comment: Thank you very much Ian, the problem was as you mentioned from the demos page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The demos page (at least in recent versions) always asks for a login. If you want to get a clear view of permissions you should use CURL or another program to test it.